# CSS display not working

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I'm really frustrated because `Display:none` isn't working on a `<tr>` element  in IE 7, what do I do? It works perfect on FF, Chrome etc...

Comment: I'm pretty damn sure it should work in IE (well, maybe not in IE3). Some more code, please?

Comment: I'll bet a great sum of money that `display: none` is working fine. Please show some more code

Comment: Version of IE + code will be helpful.

Comment: Please show some more code. `tr`'s and their `display` properties are a  special thing, but that  will usually make problems only when you try to make things *visible* again

Comment: I cannot reproduce it on my IE7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
div{
  display:none;
}
```

if not, jQuery should solve it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("div").hide();
});
```

Comment: *jQuery* to solve a basic CSS problem that shouldn't be there in the first place?

Comment: I removed my downvote, although I still don't think it's really helpful - but the OP is not specifying what the problem is exactly, so...

Comment: Actually, that helped. I put both the style and javascript up, and its working fine now. Thanks

Comment: @Famver Tags: In your free time you should consider hunting down the real problem.

Comment: What @BoltClock says, although I think it should be done straight away

Answer (score 6):

Start by checking that your code is correct using tools like these:

- [HTML Validator](http://validator.w3.org/)
- [CSS Validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/)

Comment: Whatever the circumstance, this is always a good thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

`Display:none` should be `display:none`, for one thing.

Comment: CSS is case-insensitive. @Pekka: How do you do that whitespace padding trick? :|

Comment: Sure, case insensitive, but that doesn't mean we should be insensitive to good/standardized markup.  Just looks like bad coding, is all.

Comment: you got a point, but I don't think this causes the actual problem.